# Basemap's drawgreatcirlces() function cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using Google Colab for running my program.

In this program I am trying to draw a great circle from Vancouver port to Mumbai port using matplotlib-basemap.

Getting the error 'Cannot convert float NaN to integer'.

Code here:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))

map = Basemap(projection='mill', 
              llcrnrlat=-90, 
              urcrnrlat=90, 
              llcrnrlon=-180, 
              urcrnrlon=180,
              resolution='c')

mulon = 18.9483
mulat = 72.8442
vanlon = 49.2889
vanlat = 123.1115

map.drawgreatcircle(mulon, mulat, vanlon, vanlat, color='b')

map.drawcoastlines()

map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 10), labels=[True, False, False, False])
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180, 180, 30), labels=[False, False, False, True])

plt.title('Basemap', fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

When I run this code the interpreter returns the following:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e58daae598d7> in <module>()
     13 vanlat = 123.1115
     14 
---> 15 map.drawgreatcircle(mulon, mulat, vanlon, vanlat, color='b')
     16 
     17 map.drawcoastlines()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in drawgreatcircle(self, lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, del_s, **kwargs)
   2887         gc = pyproj.Geod(a=self.rmajor,b=self.rminor)
   2888         az12,az21,dist = gc.inv(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)
-> 2889         npoints = int((dist+0.5*1000.*del_s)/(1000.*del_s))
   2890         lonlats = gc.npts(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2,npoints)
   2891         lons = [lon1]; lats = [lat1]

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Comment: `int(float('NaN'))` run this code. Note you get the same error message. The evaluation of `(dist+0.5*1000.*del_s)/(1000.*del_s)` is resulting in NaN. NaN means 'not a number', its specific to the implementation of floating point numbers - and is not unique to python or Google Colab, etc.. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Comment: TO fix the issue, I would recommend inspecting the values of `dist` and `del_s`  (using print() or a debugger) - hopefully the issue reveals itself.

Comment: Isn't it because you are specifying a latitude outside the range?

Comment: Got it.. I have interchanged the longitude and latitude values. Thanks!